# Pandas use assign/transform in pipe after a merge

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge, transform

I have two dfs

```
solar_part = pd.DataFrame(
     {'pool': 1,
     'orig': 635.1}, index = [0]
     )

solar_aod = pd.DataFrame(
     {'pool': [1,1,1,1],
      'MoP': [1,2,3,4],
     'prin': [113.1, 115.3, 456.6, 234.1]}
     )
```

Which I then merge together via pipeline and try and transform/assign a new variable

```
solar_p = (
    solar_aod
    .merge(solar_part, on = ['pool'], how = 'left')
    .assign(remn = ['prin'] / ['orig'])
    )
```

The assign (have tried transform as well) gives the error of `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'list'` which I'm guessing is caused by the bracketing. Trying only quotes gives the same same error but with `str` instead of `list`. Not including an assign/transform function and then doing it "long hand" via `solar_p.prin / solar_p.orig * 100` also works but I have several more equations to include, so I'd like it as concise as possible. How to do this tranform/assign after a merge in a pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) to create an additional column as well as [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) but the latter need to evaluate the new dataframe before use columns that why you have to use a `lambda` function here:

```
solar_p = (
    solar_aod
    .merge(solar_part, on='pool', how='left')
    .eval('remn = prin / orig')
)
```

Output:

```
>>> solar_p
   pool  MoP   prin   orig      remn
0     1    1  113.1  635.1  0.178082
1     1    2  115.3  635.1  0.181546
2     1    3  456.6  635.1  0.718942
3     1    4  234.1  635.1  0.368603
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for

```py
solar_p = (
    solar_aod
    .merge(solar_part, on = ['pool'], how = 'left')
    .assign(remn = lambda df: df['prin'] / df['orig'])
)
```

From [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) of `pandas.DataFrame.assign`,

> The column names are keywords. If the values are callable, they are computed on the DataFrame and assigned to the new columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can also first merge and then assign:

```
df = (
    solar_aod
    .merge(solar_part, on = ['pool'], how = 'left')
)

solar_p = df.assign(remn = df['prin'] / df['orig'])

print(solar_p)
```

#output

```
    pool MoP prin   orig    remn
0   1   1   113.1   635.1   0.178082
1   1   2   115.3   635.1   0.181546
2   1   3   456.6   635.1   0.718942
3   1   4   234.1   635.1   0.368603
```

Comment: This is so interesting and unexpected that the name being assigned by the workflow can be referenced within before it is actually assigned. Would not have guessed that.

Comment: this does not work, because you cannot reference `solar_p` before it is assigned. if you try running this code, an error will be thrown `NameError: name 'solar_p' is not defined`